# Generar un número aleatorio en Java que se repita más veces que los demas, se puede con random?

Tags: java, random

Necesito generar números aleatorios de un rango de números **[0-5]**, pero que **un número ** de este rango, **se repita** mas veces que todos los demás. Se puede realizar con random?

Por ejemplo que se repita el número 3 mas veces que cualquier otro número.

Comment: Buenas, se me ocurre que podrías tener un array con los valores {1,2,3,4,5,3,3}, y luego generar un índice de acceso aleatorio a este array (un numero de 0 a 6), Así, tendrías más posibilidades de que saliese el 3. Pero no puedes asegurar que te vaya a salir realmente 3 veces más, ya que sino no sería aleatorio...

Answer (score 0):

Como indica [@Rodrigo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398838/generar-un-n%C3%BAmero-aleatorio-en-java-que-se-repita-m%C3%A1s-veces-que-los-demas-se-pu#comment713277_398838), una opción es crear un array con los elementos en la proporción que quieres. Haciendo una selección aleatoria uniforme (`java.util.Random`) se seleccionan los elementos de la lista con la misma probabilidad, por lo que, al haber elementos repetidos en la lista, aumenta la probabilidad de éstos.

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] elems = { ... };
int value = elems[random.nextInt(elems.length)];
```

`random.nextInt(elems.length)` te selecciona un número aleatorio de `0` a `elems.length - 1`, que se usa como índice para seleccionar un elemento del array.

*Esto puede cumplir la función para casos simples pero, en general, es poco adecuado, tedioso y es necesario crear una lista muy larga para cuadrar probabilidades concretas.*

---

Otra opción más sencilla y menos tosca es usar alguna librería como [Apache Commons math library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/EnumeratedIntegerDistribution.html) ([maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1), [jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi)). La clase `EnumeratedIntegerDistribution` te permite indicar las probabilidades de cada elemento.

```
int[] values = { ... };
double[] probs = { ... };
        
EnumeratedIntegerDistribution dist = new EnumeratedIntegerDistribution(values, probs);
int value = dist.sample();
```

### Ejemplo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // APACHE COMMONS MATH
    // 0 = 20% | 1 = 10% | 2 = 5% | 3 = 40% | 4 = 15% | 5 = 10%
    int[] values =   {  0,   1,    2,   3,    4,   5};
    double[] probs = {0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.4, 0.15, 0.1};
    
    EnumeratedIntegerDistribution dist = new EnumeratedIntegerDistribution(values, probs);

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
    
    // Generación de 100 elementos
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int value = dist.sample();
        counter.put(value, counter.getOrDefault(value, 0) + 1);
    }
    
    System.out.println(counter);
    // {0=21, 1=8, 2=6, 3=42, 4=19, 5=4}  Los resultados variarán de una ejecución a otra
    
    
    // ------------------------------------------------
    
    // RANDOM
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> counter2 = new HashMap<>();
    
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] elems = {0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3};    // 0 = 30% | 1 = 20% | 2 = 40%, 3 = 10%
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int value = elems[random.nextInt(elems.length)];
        counter2.put(value, counter2.getOrDefault(value, 0) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(counter2);
    // {0=38, 1=20, 2=32, 3=10}
    
}
```